# DynamoDB give Error, when execute a command. How to solve it?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

**Before not execute any command of AWS dynamodb command successful install**

```
DynamoDB Local with the following configuration:
Port:   8000
InMemory:       false
DbPath: null
SharedDb:       true
shouldDelayTransientStatuses:   false
CorsParams:     *
```

**After execute a dynamodb command in CMD terminal it is give an error**

```
Port:   8000
InMemory:       false
DbPath: null
SharedDb:       true
shouldDelayTransientStatuses:   false
CorsParams:     *
Aug 18, 2022 3:55:46 PM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
WARNING: [sqlite] [DELETE FROM sm WHERE DeletionDateTime < ?;]DB[1][C]: exception when clearing
com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteException: [8] DB[1] reset [attempt to write a readonly database]
        at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection.throwResult(SQLiteConnection.java:1436)
        at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection.throwResult(SQLiteConnection.java:1409)
```

**CMD Command in another terminal then it is give error and above error at same time**

```
aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
An error occurred (InternalFailure) when calling the ListTables operation (reached max retries: 2): The request processing has failed because of an unknown error, exception or failure.
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Still not found